# View PDF file and not download

Tags: php, pdf, pdfviewer

I want the user to view a PDF file without being able to save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) or print (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) the document. The user should neither be able to copy the text inside the PDF. Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the document is visible in the users browser then there is nothing you can do to prevent the user from taking a screenshot - so the user can always copy your content in some fashion. Print Screen / Screenshot is basically the same thing.

In terms of not wanting to allow the user to download the PDF - which if you send the PDF as-is to the browser and it opens it inline most browsers offer a download option -- then you should look into rendering the PDF using Javascript.

Comment: Couldn't someone still download the rendered PDF by tracing the JavaScript code?

Comment: @Froopy yes, thats still possible. Ultimately there is no end-all solution; at best you can just force the user to jump thru more hoops.